# ModuleNotFoundError with python after module installed

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I'm running python 3.5.

I've tried everything that I could find on StackOverflow with no success.

When I install hitbtc module, it gets installed and I can see the files in the python\lib\site-packages module. The __init__.py file looks fine and should work.

when it try to import it in my script(below) in wont run and give me an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hitbtc'

```
import hitbtc
```

or

```
from hitbtc import HitBTC
```

Every other installed module works fine.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the module no success.

But interestingly, it won't give me any error if I import it trough the terminal.

I'm out of ideas. Anyone?

Edit:

I have only 1 python version installed 3.5 and i run the file trough cmd just calling file.py

Comment: Any chance you run different versions of Python each time? (When running the script vs. when running through the terminal)

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: @DanielRoseman trough cmd. Calling file.py

Comment: @Neo I have only 1 python version installed. So that souldn't be an issue.

Comment: import `sys` and `print('\n'.join(sys.path))` in both the terminal and by running the file.  This shows the paths python should be looking through when trying to import packages.  Since you can import it from terminal and not from the file, I would expect these two to be different.

Comment: @e.s. you're right, I found the issue. Thanks. :)